# Flutter GestureDetector with multiple futures

Tags: flutter, dart

I got 2 futures. When I press a GestureDetector I want the first to be completed and then run the second one. But it doesn’t work. What can I do to fix the issue?

Here is my code.

```
GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => pickImage(), uploadImageToFirebase(),
),

Future pickImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      _imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
    });
  }

  Future uploadImageToFirebase(BuildContext context) async {
    String fileName = basename(_imageFile.path);
    StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('uploads/$fileName');
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_imageFile);
    StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
    taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(
          (value) => imageUrl = value,
        );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Future.wait()` , It takes a `List` of `Futures` and return when all underlying future completes/resolves.

In your code, You can do something like this,

```
GestureDetector(
 onTap: () => pickImageandUploadToFirebase(),
),
```

The method `pickImageandUploadToFirebase()` looks like this,

```
Future<void> pickImageandUploadToFirebase() async {
 await Future.wait([
  pickImage(),
  uploadImageToFirebase(),
 ]);
}
```

and you already have the 2 methods `pickImage()` and `uploadImageToFirebase()`
Hope this helps, Happy fluttering !

Answer (score 0):

upload this after image pick done,
like this

```
  GestureDetector(
  onTap: () => pickImage(context);
  ),

  Future pickImage(context) async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      _imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
    });
    uploadImageToFirebase(context);
  }

  Future uploadImageToFirebase(BuildContext context) async {
    String fileName = basename(_imageFile.path);
    StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =
    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('uploads/$fileName');
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_imageFile);
    StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
    taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(
          (value) => imageUrl = value,
    );
  }
```

also, another option is if you need to call one by one in single method.
then return data from first method "pickImage" after retrun done, you call second "uploadImageToFirebase",